# Question about the Quotient norm in a banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I am trying to show that the image of the unit ball under the quotient projection is the unit ball in the quotient space, I'm new to working with cosets/quotient norms so I am wondering if my attempt at a proof of the following statement is correct.

Consider a normed linear space $X$, and a closed subspace $M$, and let $\pi : X \to X/M$ be the quotient projection, so $\pi f = f+M$ for any $f \in X$.

Let $f \in X$ arbitrary, $B_X(f,r)$ be the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $f$. I want to show that:

$$
\pi B_X(f,r) = B_{X/M}(f+M, r)
$$
where:
$$
\pi B_X(f,r) = \{ g+M: \| g-f\| < r\}
$$
and 
$$
B_{X/M}(f+M, r) = \{g +M :  \|(g+M) - (f+M)\| = \| (g-f) + M\| < r \}
$$

I first show that $B_{X/M}(f+M, r) \subseteq \pi B_X(f,r)$, then:

So if $g+M \in B_{X/M}(f+M, r)$, then:
\begin{align*}
\| g+ M \| &= \|(g-f) + M \| < r\\
\implies & \inf_{m \in M} \| (g-f) + m \| \le \|g-f \|  < r
\end{align*}
Since $0 \in M$ for any subspace. We therefore have that $g \in B_X(f,r)$ and so $\pi g \in \pi B_X(f,r)$.

In the other direction, if we take an arbitrary $h \in  B_X(f,r)$, then $h + M \in \pi B_X(f,r)$, and we want to show that $h+M \in B_{X/M}(f+M, r)$.

\begin{align*}
\| (h+ M) - (f+M) \| &= \| (h-f) + M \|\\
&= \inf_{m \in M } \|h-f-m \|\\
& \le \| h-f\|\\
& < r.
\end{align*}
Therefore $h+m \in B_{X/M}(f+M, r)$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: Why is $\|g-f\| < r$? This reasoning is false.

Comment: The second part is ok though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, the first part of your proof is false. So, choose $g+M\in B_{X/M}(f+M,r)$. Then $\inf_{m\in M}\|g-f-m\| < r$. So, there exists $m\in M$ such that $\|(g-m)-f\| < r$. Hence, $g-m\in B_X(f,r)$ and $\pi(g-m) = g+M$. That's it.

Comment: thanks, that was a silly mistake -.-

Comment: Wow, that was a fast reaction... :o)

Comment: haha.. I was in the process of editing it when i saw you had posted a solution